# Can anyone tell me how to make guake terminal be part of the start-up applications?

Tags: command-line, startup-applications, guake

How can I add Guake terminal to the start-up applications?

Answer (score 1):

Press `Super` to bring up the dash, type "startup applications" in. I believe Guake puts itself (unchecked) in the list already, otherwise create a new entry which uses the command `guake`.

(This is just a more specific version of this question: [How do I start applications automatically on login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login))